# JMeter - Specify CSV row failure

Tags: csv, jmeter

Within JMeter, I am running a script which uses a .CSV file to enter data as well as verify results. It is working correctly, but I cannot figure out how to tell which row/line of the .CSV caused the individual failures. Is there a way to do this?

Somewhat of an example scenario (not specific to what I'm doing, but similar):
Each row of the .CSV file contains a mathematical equation as well as the expected result.

On page 1, enter the equation (2+2)

Then on Page 2, you get the response: 3.

That test would obviously be a failure.

Say there are 1,000 tests being ran, some that pass and some that do not. How can I tell which .CSV row/line didn't pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any columns in your CSV file which help you to uniquely identify a row?

- Let me assume you have a column called 'TestCaseNo' which has values as TC001, TC002,TC003...etc
- Add a Beanshell Post Processor to store the result for each iteration.
- Add the below code. I assume the you have the PASS or FAIL result stored in the 'Result' variable.

  ```
  import java.io.File;
  import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

  f = new FileOutputStream("someptah/tcstatus.csv", true); 
  p = new PrintStream(f); 
  p.println( vars.get("TestCaseNo") + "," + vars.get("Result"));
  p.close();
  f.close();
  ```
- The above code creates a CSV file with the results for each testcase.

**EDIT:**

Do the assertion yourself in the Beanshell post processor.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

   Result = "FAIL";
   Response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
   if (Response.contains("value")) // replace the value with the expected text
       Result = "PASS";

    f = new FileOutputStream("someptah/tcstatus.csv", true); 
    p = new PrintStream(f); 
    p.println( vars.get("TestCaseNo") + "," + Result);
    p.close();
    f.close();
```

Comment: Yes, Vinoth, there is an identifier column called 'Iteration' and then it's just numbered 1 - x.I am currently using the Response Assertion and capturing using substrings of the text response to create pass/fail a each test case. If I can just figure out how to store the result in a variable, I'll be set! Searching now... That code, however, is PERFECT! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: This could be my "noob"-ness, but the response data is an entire HTML webpage. I capture a substring of that page and compare that with the value in the .CSV file. I have been trying to implement the additional code you provided, but it is not working out. I just keep getting null as the Result. I even tried just printing the Response and that came out as null as well.

Comment: @dcnorman07, Result is null because i did not put that outside. Now corrected. Response should have the entire HTML response. Can you upload the screenshot of the testplan?

Comment: Ya, I just realized the original EDIT was trying to print the string as a var. I just need to grab the substring of the HTML and I think I'm set. I appreciate your solution. Will work great!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following approach

1. [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function - to get data from the .csv file.
2. [__counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function - to track CSV file position. You can include counter variable name into Sampler's label so current .csv file line could be reported. See below image for example

[image: Counter]

For more information on aforementioned and other useful JMeter functions see [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series.

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, OP was asking for the result file generation with PASS/FAIL status after each iteration. Can we update the same CSV file JMeter uses with CSV dataset config.?

Comment: In case of immense load it will be quite tricky, also the file won't be reusable after update so I would rather go for creating a separate file via i.e. [Flexible File Writer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/), however if the topicstarter is looking for line number only my approach with the counter should be OK

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for clarifying. Never tried 'Flexible File writer' - i ll check . I have learnt many things from your answers in SO. Thanks